# Sharings stopped working on Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion

After upgrading to Lion, my USB hard drive(not only USB, see below) share is no longer accessible. I can see the shared folder, but when I try to enter from Windows 7 box it says `Windows cannot access \\path\\to\\usbsharedresource`.

Even BOOTCAMP partition which was shared and working now inaccessible...

Comment: Have you checked the settings in Sharing preferences pane, as well as the folder permissions for shared folders?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Sharing preferences are same, shared resources are in "Shared Folders" listbox. I don't think for NTFS folders I can specify permissions unless there is some new hidden checkbox somewhere.